# AVAssetWriter / AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor - black frames and frame rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm capturing the camera feed and writing it to a movie.
The problem I'm having is that after the export the movie has a couple of black seconds in front of it (relative to the actual recording start time).

I think this is related to `[self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];`
I had a half working solution by having a frameStart variable that just counted upwards in the samplebuffer delegate method.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    frameStart++;
    if (self.startRecording == YES) {

        static int64_t frameNumber = 0;
        if(self.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
            [self.pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameNumber, 25)];
        }
        frameNumber++;
    }
}
```

and then call this method when the user pressed a button:

```
[self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(frameStart,25)];
```

this works. but only once... if I want to record a second movie the black frames are back again.

Also, when I look at the outputted movie the frame rate is 25fps like I want it to. but the video looks as if it's sped up. as if there is not enough space between the frames. So the movie plays about twice as fast.

```
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:640], AVVideoWidthKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey, AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];

self.assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:outputSettings];
self.assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to count frame timestamps on your own. You can get the timestamp of the current sample with

```
CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
```

However, it seems to me you are just passing the pixel buffer of the frame to the adaptor without modifications. Wouldn't it be easier to pass the sample buffer itself directly to the `assetWriterInput` like the following?

```
[self.assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
```

Comment: this is actually very close. I just have one question. How would I get the timestamp on a button press? Right now, I have CMTime variable `latestTimestamp`that keeps getting the timestamp from the last frame in the `captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` method. Then when the user presses a button I do`[self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:self.latestFrameTimeStamp];` This works but I'm guessing there should be a better way.

Comment: That's actually what I do: start the recording session with the timestamp of the first sample coming in after the user pressed the button. If you really take the moment the user pressed the button as starting point, you could end up with some blank frames at the beginning of the video due to the capture delay.

Comment: But how would I get that first sample? Because the sample can only be obtained in the sample buffer delegate method right? suppose I have a method `-(void) buttonPressed`. And In there I invoke this method `[self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:timestamp];
` How would I then get the last `timestamp` from the delegate method into my button pressed method? (in a good way)

Comment: You should rather set a flag when the user presses the button—like `self.recording = YES;`. In the capture delegate method you can then check `if (self.recording && self.assetWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {[self.assetWriter startWriting]; [self.assetWriter startSessionAt...]; ...}`. This way it will start recording when the first sample arrives.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you incrementing frameNumber twice for every frame? 
Increment once, remove the first one.
This should fix the playback speed.

Second, are you resetting frameNumber to 0 when you finish recording?
If not than this is your problem.
If not I need more explanation about what is going on here..

Regards